# createPartialMock with MocksControl

Tags: java, easymock, powermock

I have a `StrictPartialMock` (created with `createStrictPartialMock(class, "method1")`). and a normal `mockedObject`.

I want to test if `method1()` calls `StrictPartialMock.method2()`, `mockedObject.method1()`, `StrictPartialMock.method3()` in that order.

Now i read i can use `private IMocksControl ctrl = createStrictControl();` to create a control that can check the order of method calls between mocks, but `IMocksControl` does not support `createPartialMock()`.

Is there any way to combine these 2 techniques?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've currently worked around this problem by extending the class i'm testing instead. I was already doing this because my class under test was `abstract`, but i guess this is possible as long as it's not `final`.

```
@test
public voide testCase() {
    IMocksControl ctrl = createStrictControl();
    OrderTester mockedOrderTester = ctrl.createMock(OrderTester.class);
    MyObject mockedMyObject = ctrl.createMock(MyObject.class);
    mockedOrderTester.method2()
    expectLastCall();
    mockedMyObject .method1()
    expectLastCall();
    mockedOrderTester.method3()
    expectLastCall();
    ctrl.replay();
    ClassUnderTestExt testClass = new ClassUnderTestExt();
    testClass.ot = mockedOrderTester;
    testClass.mo = mockedMyObject;
    testClass.method1();
    ctrl.verify();
}


class ClassUnderTestExt extends ClassUnderTest<String> {
    public OrderTester ot;
    public MyObject mo;

    @Override
    public void writeOutput(String data) {
    }

    @Override
    public void method2() {
        super.method2();
        ot.method2();
    }

    @Override
    public void method3() {
        super.method3();
        ot.method3();
    }
}

class OrderTester {
    public void method2() {
    }

    public void method3() {
    }
}
```

Notice you can leave out `super.methodX();` to simulate true partialmocking.

But this solution is far from perfect. It would be way less work if this could have been done with partial mocking and a IMocksControl

Comment: Accepting my own questions, how sad. Seems this is overlooked in IMocksControl. I guess i should bug the PowerMock people about this if i ever get time for it.